# ASP.NET MVC 3 Cookies get lost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, session-cookies

I am sending domain cookies from one site to my asp.net mvc application , there I setting Authentication cookie ,

In My Action Filter I can't see that cookie appears , but if I am looking in BeginRequest event of global.asax there is cookie there. Any Ideas why cookies getting lost on their way to the Action Filter ?

Thanks.

Adding of

```
 <machineKey validationKey="4B79DF965DC586D2B267BDECB4580D40EE6811EE171AC65D929BECD8865C09ED8681B92F2177FE9F72B8E822B26914C79C1FF590CCEE65469CBC6FACD7D9F203" decryptionKey="SOmeKey" validation="SHA1" />
```

doesn't helped...

Don't know what to do with this...
Update2:
I can see in Application_BeginRequest - 2 cookies , then when break point hits my custom action filter

```
public class SecurityFilter : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
```

Here my first cookie dissapearing , and second is still exists.
the Expire property is set the same for both , and every property except value is the same in both cookies , why the first one gets lost ? and the second is exist ? Reading about ASP.NET MVC request pipeline doesn't opened my eyes on something , anyone please :-)

Comment: You are working crossdomain? Because cookies are bounded on a domain.

Comment: It's same domain , mvc application is back office for the site , and sitting under the same domain , and In Begin_Request event I can see cookie , then in Action Filter it doesn't appears

Comment: Maby helpfull links [link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557066/net-mvc-write-cookie-from-actionfilter), [link 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399568/asp-mvc-3-actionfilter-for-basic-authentication)

Comment: Are you talking about the .ASPXAUTH cookie? Are you settings its path when it's written?

Comment: Yes , it's ASPAUTH cookie , and path is ="/" root of domain...

Comment: From sniffer :  domain=aspmvc-dev.com; path=/